# Why is $\{(x,y)\mid X\times Y: \phi(x)=\psi(y)\}$ quasi-projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose you have two regular maps $\phi\colon X\to Z$ and $\psi\colon Y\to Z$, which are regular maps of quasi-projective varieties. I have jotted down (from a little informal talk a while ago) that the set $$\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid\phi(x)=\psi(y)\}$$ is a quasi-projective variety itself. Everything was over an algebraically closed field, if it simplifies matters.

I have two little questions. Is there a name for this type of object? It reminded me somewhat of the equalizer except the maps have the same target, not domain. And is there a source where it is explained why it's also quasi-projective?

Comment: As a set, it's the categorical pullback (i.e. fiber product) of the maps $\phi$ and $\psi$. I think that's still true as varieties, but I'm not positive.

Comment: It can be seen as the equalizer of the two maps $\phi\circ\pi_1$ and $\psi\circ \pi_2$ from $X\times Y\to Z$. But pullback is probably the correct term.